# Unkown Attribute Error Rails 5.1.1 - not recognizing model attribute with join table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-console

I will present my files, my process, then the error in this post.

**Problem**
Rails console is not recognizing my model attribute on a join table.

(if you can think of a better way to describe the problem/or ask this question after reading below, let me know in your reply as it will help me to learn what it is I am attempting to ask for.)

**Files**

models/admin_user.rb

```
class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :pages
    has_many :section_edits
end
```

models/section.rb

```
class Section < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :page
    has_many :section_edits

end
```

models/section_edit.rb

```
class SectionEdit < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :sections
    belongs_to :admin_users

end
```

tables from schema.rb

```
create_table "admin_users", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|
    t.string "first_name", limit: 25
    t.string "last_name", limit: 50
    t.string "email", limit: 100, default: "", null: false
    t.string "username", limit: 25
    t.string "hashed_password", limit: 40
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_admin_users_on_username"
  end

create_table "section_edits", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|
    t.integer "admin_user_id"
    t.integer "section_id"
    t.string "summary"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["section_id", "admin_user_id"], name: "index_section_edits_on_section_id_and_admin_user_id"
end

create_table "sections", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|
    t.integer "page_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "position"
    t.boolean "visible", default: false
    t.string "content_type"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["page_id"], name: "index_sections_on_page_id"
end
```

**Process**

1. I boot up rails console using rails -c on cloud9 IDE.
2. I create an AdminUser and assign to variable "me".
   below is the return value for variable "me":

   > me

   ```
   => <#AdminUser id: 1, first_name: "john", last_name: "smith", email:"", username: "jsmith", hashed_password: nil, created_at: "2017-06-17 14:00:44", updated_at: "2017-06-17 14:00:44">
   ```
3. I create a Section and assign to a variable "section"
   below is the return value for "section":

   > section

   ```
   => <#Section id: 1, page_id: nil, name: "Section One", position: 1, visible: false, content_type: nil, content: nil, created_at: "2017-06-17 14:20:08", updated_at: "2017-06-17 14:20:08">
   ```
4. I attempt to create a new SectionEdit as follows:

   > edit = SectionEdit.new(:summary => 'Test Edit', :admin_user => me, :section => section)

**ERROR**

rails console throws back this error at me :

```
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'admin_user' for SectionEdit.
    from (irb):24
```

I performed all this while watching and following along with lynda.com's rails 5 tutorial.  This is irritating because the instructor is able to accomplish the instance creation and save it to the DB. Did I miss something in rails 5 -> 5.1.1 ? any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use singular names in `SectionEdit` model:

```
class SectionEdit < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :section
    belongs_to :admin_user
end
```